Show block author
I have created a new substrate blockchain using the frontier node template.
https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Falice.ekratos.cat#/explorer
Everything works, but in the Polkadot portal, the recent blocks only show the block number and hash but do not show the block author (like I see in all other networks).
Why?

You need the pallet-authorship pallet. Add it to your runtime, and you can see the author of every block.
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/3fcdada318bfee0b8da945b78496a8191375cf26/templates/parachain/runtime/src/configs/mod.rs#L134

I am using Frontier: https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier
How to add this pallet-authorship in Frontier? I don't find the mod.rs file there

Just like how you add other pallets to your frontier project.
For example, my team's chain is a also a frontier chain https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/4728073b752525661e495135fc0fbc58ceaba5a5/runtime/darwinia/src/lib.rs#L110
and
https://github.com/darwinia-network/darwinia/blob/4728073b752525661e495135fc0fbc58ceaba5a5/runtime/darwinia/src/pallets/authorship.rs#L22-L25

There is no function "construct_runtime" in the frontier runtime file, which I assume is this one: https://github.com/polkadot-evm/frontier/blob/master/template/runtime/src/lib.rs

Yes, they just did an upgrade. Putting it in #[frame_support::runtime] will make it works.
